# Diffuse materials under glass dome turning black (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, glass

I have what is essentially a glass dome modeled with internal and external faces, but Diffuse materials under it always turn nearly black no matter how smooth or what color the glass is.[image]

To demonstrate, I put a white Diffuse cube under the dome, and you can see how it looks almost completely black.
The materials are all really simple with no extra nodes.
[image: Glass Nodes]
[image: Diffuse Nodes]

Comment: Could you show us your node setup for both materials? I cannot reproduce this issue. Or upload blend file.

Comment: I added the nodes.